# Prove that $\mathbb{F}[x]/(f(x))$,is a vector space of dimension n

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that for each polynomial degree of $n \ge 1$, the elements {$1,x,x^2,...,x^{n-1}$}are a basis of the vector space $\mathbb{F}[x]/(f(x))$ where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

Let $f(x)=a_n.x^n+..+a_o$ . Any polynomial $g(x)=g_nx^n+..+g_o$ in the quotient ring will look like $g_o(x)=g_n(-a_n^{-1}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+(-a_n^{-1}.a_o))+....+g_o$.

$g_o(x)=g_n^{'}x^{n-1}+...+g_o^{'}$

So the distinctcosets will be $h(x)+<f(x)>$ where h(x) are polynomials of degree $1,2,3,,,n-1$ and since $\mathbb{F}$ is a field,it is an euclidean domain and so is $\mathbb{F}[x]$ .Thus we can use division algorithm over here. So how would $h(x)$ look like? Will $h(x)$ look like $x^{n-1},..,1$ if so then in which coset would $g_o(x)$ belong to?

Comment: Did you the try good old "1) B spans the vector space 2) B is linearly independent"-approach?

Comment: @Stockfish I would try that but my question is $F[x]/(f(x))$ would be a quotient ring,  in which cost would $g_o(x)$ go to?

Comment: You use $g_o$ as both the constant term and the name of the reduced polynomial. That's not a good thing. Also, it looks better (at least to me) to use $g_0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "cost" ? Also I'm not sure about your question, an element of $\mathbb{F}[x]/(f(x))$ looks like $g(x)+(f(x))$ which is the same as $g(x)-f(x)+(f(x)) = g(x)+2f(x)+(f(x)) = ...$

Answer (score 1):

First of all $\mathbb{F}[x]$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ spanned by the basis $(x^i)_{i \ge 0}$.

Let $V = \mathbb{F}[x]/(f(x))$ for some polynomial $f$. This quotient is also a vector space (for details see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra) ).

Now we know that from basic facts about quotient spaces that $(x^i)_{i \ge 0}$ spans $V$ but it is no longer a basis because quotienting by $f$ creates linear relations between the elements that weren't there before.

The elements

- $1 + (f(x))$
- $x + (f(x))$
- $x^2 + (f(x))$
- ...
- $x^{n-1} + (f(x))$

are all distinct, and all elements $x^{m} + (f(x))$ ($m \ge n$) are expressible in terms of the $n$ basis elements above - you can see this by simply subtracting off the high order terms using $f$.